# Redstone builds on Lumia 520

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, redstone-builds

only selected new phones are getting redstone builds, remaining including my 520 are getting threshold build, latest being 10586.318.
 Is there any possibility to get Redstone Upgrade in my phone.
I tried changing Phone manufacturer name (from NOKIA to MicrosoftMDG) and hardware variant (eg, for 520, its RM_914) to that of 950 XL (RM-1085-113025) but still cant get the update.
 Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

**No,it is not possible** *(at least officially)*.

RedStone builds are available for phones that are eligible for Windows 10 insider preview. I'm sorry to say that your phone model is not in the list of eligible phones for Insider preview. As a matter of fact Lumia 520 is not even qualified for the official Windows 10 upgrade.

Therefore there will be no new builds to your phone.

You can see the list of eligible phones in the below links :

1. [Supported phones for Insider preview - Microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-supported-phones)
2. [Phones eligible for windows 10 upgrade - Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10specs#upgavailphone)

Comment: i know its not possible officially, previously i tried registry hacking and got 14291, but due to some problems , i went back with threshold builds (10586.xxx) , but when i tried the same to get latest build 14356, am not getting it!!

Comment: @RAMRAJ It may be possible with a registry hack. But it is strictly not recommended as the latest OS may not run well on your device provided the minimum RAM required is 1GB.

Comment: yes, i left it. Registry Hack wasnt working anyway!